# JQuery Datatable - Split single cell into multiple columns for readability?

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

With JQuery Data tables, is it possible to split a single column up into parts purely for readability? For example, I have a databases of URLs split into the domain and the path. I want to keep the path whole, but for readability I would like each part of the path split up into columns. For example:

```
DOMAIN | PATH
www.xxx| /p | /rty |   |
www.zzz| /o |      |   |
www.yyy| /yu| /x   | /t|
```

I have tried using *render* to split up each URL with spaces, but this is less than ideal as everything is within the same column and rather an eyesore.

*EDIT* Just to be clear, I would really like to keep the path as one data entry. I am aware this is an odd choice, but in my case it is preferable.

*EDIT* Code to fill in the table

Javascript

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#ut-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! url('/all') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'frequency'},
            { data: 'occurrences'},
            { data: 'protocol'},
            { data: 'domain'},
            { data: 'path', render: function(data, type, row){
                var newchar = '  |  ';
                return data.split('/').join(newchar);
                }
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="ut-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>frequency</th>
        <th>occurrences</th>
        <th>protocol</th>
        <th>domain</th>
        <th>path</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


Laravel Back End

public function all()
{
    Debugbar::warning('query fired');
    return Datatables::of(
        Unknown_Tag::query()
        ->orderBy('frequency', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('urlTrimmed')
    )->make(true);
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks a million to Louys and his answer, however I still have a problem. I need to split up my path, not my url. EX I need to split this:
"/this/is/my/path"
into this:
this is my path
I tried the below code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var table = $('#ut-table');
    table.dataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! url('/all') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'domain'},
            { data: 'path', render: function(data, type, row){
                var regexp = /^\/.*?(?=\/|$)/g;
                var match = regexp.exec(data);
                return match[0];
            }
            },
            { data: 'path', render: function(data, type, row){
                var regexp = /^\/.*?(?=\/|$)/g;
                var match = regexp.exec(data);
                return match[1];
            }
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

However, since both calls to my regex are in different scopes, only my first match will be returned. Any idea how I can get around this without having to run a loop for each iteration?
Actually, this thought just came to me, is there anyway I can edit the JSON from my PHP call to include the split up path?

Comment: Show how you fill the Datatable data...

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a regular expression like this one : `/^(https?:\/\/)(.+\/)(.+)/`.

So, assuming your data is in JSON formed like in [this example](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#Examples).
And that you have ONE JSON attribute containg the full URL.

Say... Something like this:

```
{
    "frequency":{value},
    "occurrences":{value},
    "fullurl":{value}
}
```

Your function would look like:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ut-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! url('/all') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'frequency'},
            { data: 'occurrences'},
            { data: 'fullurl', render: function(data, type, row){
                var regexp = /^(https?:\/\/)(.+\/)(.+)/;
                var match = regexp.exec(data);
                return match[0];                        // PROTOCOL
                }
            },
            { data: 'fullurl', render: function(data, type, row){
                var regexp = /^(https?:\/\/)(.+\/)(.+)/;
                var match = regexp.exec(data);
                return match[1];                        // DOMAIN
                }
            },
            { data: 'fullurl', render: function(data, type, row){
                var regexp = /^(https?:\/\/)(.+\/)(.+)/;
                var match = regexp.exec(data);
                return match[2];                        // PATH
                }
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

So the regular expression has 3 possible "matches" determined by the parenthesis.
The trick is to return the right match in the right column.

[image]

You can test your own regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/#javascript).

Hoping it helps!
;)

---

**EDIT**

To "split" the path only... instead of the full URL, as asked in comments:

You better use the `.split` function then.
Because this part will not be as "regular" has the previous case.
It can have different sub-directory level...
It can have a trailing slash and sometimes not.

So let say you have 4 columns, like for the example you provided : "/this/is/my/path"

Since the function is a bit longuer, I think it is best to avoid having it repeated 4 times.
So let's create a function to place in global scope.

```
// This var is the real column amount of your table (not zero-based).
var maxPathParts = 4;

function pathSplitter(pathPart){

    // Check if the first char is a / and remove if it's the case.
    // It would oddly make the first array element as empty.
    if(data.charAt(0)=="/"){
        data = data.sustr(1);
    }

    // Check if last char is a slash.
    var lastWasSlash=false;
    if(data.charAt(data.length-1)=="/"){
        lastWasSlash=true;
        data = data.substr(0,data.length-1);
    }

    // Now split the data in an array based on slashes.
    var splittedData = data.split("/");

    // If there is more parts than maxPathParts... Aggregate all the excedent in the last part.
    if(splittedData.length>maxPathParts){
        var tempLastPart;
        for(i=maxPathParts-1;i<splittedData.length;i++){
        tempLastPart += splittedData[i] + "/";
        }
        splittedData[maxPathParts]=tempLastPart;
    }

    // If it exist.
    if(typeof(splittedData[pathPart]!="undefined"){

        // Add a trailing slash to it if it is not the last element.
        if( pathPart != splittedData.length-1 ){

            // Add a trailing slash to it.
            splittedData[pathPart] += "/";
        }

        // But add it anyway if the last char of the path was a slash.
        if (pathPart != splittedData.length-1 && lastWasSlash ){

            // Add a trailing slash to it.
            splittedData[pathPart] += "/";
        }
        return splittedData[pathPart];

    }else{
        // If there is no value for this column.
        return "";
    }
}
```

So now that you have a function, just call it in the DataTable column settings with the right column number as argument:

```
columns: [
    { data: 'domain'},
    { data: 'path', render: pathSplitter(0)},
    { data: 'path', render: pathSplitter(1)},
    { data: 'path', render: pathSplitter(2)},
    { data: 'path', render: pathSplitter(3)},
],
```

Let me know it it bugs...
I didn't test anything.

Comment: Wow, tasty! I may well have to use this! :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help, you really helped me understand how data tables works. However, this is not quite what I need. See my updated post

Comment: I udated my answer, considering only the path. ;)