# Data Is Not Being Added to Jquery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datatables

So I am trying to build an app using AngularJS.  I am trying to create a table to display contact information with info being populated in different rows.  I also want to be able to add new contacts to that table. Here is what the table looks like: [image of contact table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxfJZ.png).[image]

This is the form to add new contacts when you press the "Add Row" button: [image of "add a contact" form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvkfk.png). [image]

The HTML code I will show is part of a partial template so if you try to run it, it will be unstyled. If you look in the javascript portion, the greyed out areas are different scenarios I would try to force the information. I've been working to solve this solution all day, and I can't seem to find the solution.  Any advice on what I could possibly be doing wrong in my code? Here is the code:

```js
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('app', [])
    
    .controller('TableWithDynamicRowsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var table = $('#tableWithDynamicRows');

        $scope.options = {
            "sDom": "<'table-responsive't><'row'<p i>>",
            
            "destroy": true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ ",
                "sInfo": "Showing <b>_START_ to _END_</b> of _TOTAL_ entries"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        };
        
  $scope.contact = {};
     $scope.addContact = function(){
         /*$scope.contacts = {'name': $scope.contact.name, 'company': $scope.contact.company, 'address': $scope.contact.address, 'city': $scope.contact.city, 'state': $scope.contact.state, 'zip': $scope.contact.zip, 'email': $scope.contact.email, 'phone': $scope.contact.phone, 'notes': $scope.contact.notes, 'status': $scope.contact.status};*/
         $scope.employees.push({name: $scope.name, company: $scope.company, address: $scope.address, city: $scope.city, state: $scope.state, zip: $scope.zip, email: $scope.email, phone: $scope.phone, notes: $scope.notes, status: $scope.status});
         $scope.contacts = {};
         for(var i in $scope.employees){
             console.log($scope.employees[i]);
         }
          $('#addNewAppModal').modal('hide');
         
     };
        

        $scope.showModal = function() {
            $('#addNewAppModal').modal('show');
        }
        $scope.addApp = function() {
           
            table.dataTable().fnAddData([
                 
                $("#appName").val(), 
                $("#appCompany").val(),
                $("#appAddress").val() + $("#appCity").val() + ',' + $("#appState").val() +  $("#appZip").val() ,
               /* $("#appCity").val(),
                $("#appState").val(),
                $("#appZip").val(),*/
                $("#appEmail").val(),
                $("#appPhone").val(),
                $("#appNotes").val(),
                $("#appStatus").val()
            ]);
           
            

            
            
        }
        
         $scope.employees = [
             
         { name: "Donald Trump", company: "Being President", address: "Trump Tower", city: "NYC", state: "NY", zip: "77093", email: "iamthebest@gmail.com", phone: "(713) 226-2462", notes: "Tax", status: "Active" },
         
          { name: "Dora the Explorer", company: "Exploring the World", address: "Nickelodian", city: "Santa Fe", state: "NM", zip: "77093", email: "theoutback@gmail.com", phone: "(713) 226-2462", notes: "Education", status: "Inactive"},
         
          { name: "Harry Potter", company: "Hogwarts", address: "3800 Hopper Rd", city: "London", state: "England", zip: "77093", email: "pottertheson@gmail.com", phone: "(713) 226-2462", notes: "Education", status: "Active"},
         
          { name: "Lily Potter", company: "Housewife", address: "3800 Hopper Rd", city: "Beyond the Grave", state: "Underworld", zip: "77093", email: "potterthemother@gmail.com", phone: "(713) 226-2462", notes: "Bookkeeping", status: "Inactive"},
         
          { name: "James Potter", company: "Tormenting Snape", address: "Hogwarts Blvd", city: "Beyond the Grave", state: "Underworld", zip: "77093", email: "potter@gmail.com", phone: "(713) 226-2462", notes: "Tax", status: "Inactive"},
         
         { name: "Severus Snape", company: "Professor at Hogwarts", address: "Betrayal St", city: "London", state: "England", zip: "77093", email: "ilovelily@gmail.com", phone: "(713) 226-2462", notes: "Education", status: "Inactive"},
     ];
      

    }])

    .controller('TableWithExportOptionsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {


        var table = $('#tableWithExportOptions');


        $scope.options = {
            "sDom": "<'exportOptions'T><'table-responsive't><'row'<p i>>",
            
            "destroy": true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ ",
                "sInfo": "Showing <b>_START_ to _END_</b> of _TOTAL_ entries"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [{
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sButtonText": "<i class='pg-grid'></i>",
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sButtonText": "<i class='fa fa-file-excel-o'></i>",
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sButtonText": "<i class='fa fa-file-pdf-o'></i>",
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "copy",
                    "sButtonText": "<i class='fa fa-copy'></i>",
                }]
            },
            fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings) {
                $('.export-options-container').append($('.exportOptions'));

                $('#ToolTables_tableWithExportOptions_0').tooltip({
                    title: 'Export as CSV',
                    container: 'body'
                });

                $('#ToolTables_tableWithExportOptions_1').tooltip({
                    title: 'Export as Excel',
                    container: 'body'
                });

                $('#ToolTables_tableWithExportOptions_2').tooltip({
                    title: 'Export as PDF',
                    container: 'body'
                });

                $('#ToolTables_tableWithExportOptions_3').tooltip({
                    title: 'Copy data',
                    container: 'body'
                });
            }
        };

    }]);


/* .controller('AddContactsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.contact = {};
     $scope.addContact = function($scope.employees){
         $scope.employees.push($scope.contact);
         $scope.contact = {};
     };
     
     

   }]);*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- START PANEL -->
    <div class="panel panel-transparent" ng-controller="TableWithDynamicRowsCtrl">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button id="show-modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" ng-click="showModal()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add row</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    
  
  
                    <form class="search-container" id="tableWithSearch" action="//llamaswill.tumblr.com/search">
  <input id="search-box" type="text" class="search-box" name="q" ng-model="searchText"/>
  <label for="search-box"><span class="search-icon"><i class="pg-search"></i></span></label>
  <input type="submit" id="search-submit" />
</form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-hover demo-table-dynamic" id="tableWithDynamicRows" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="options">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                         <th>Email</th>
                         <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:searchText">
                        <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p><span data-letters="{{ employee.name | limitTo: 1 }}"  id="avatar" onload="return ran_col()" onmouseover="return ran_col()"></span>{{ employee.name }}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p>{{ employee.company }}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p>{{ employee.address }}<br> {{ employee.city }}, {{ employee.state }} {{ employee.zip }}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p>{{ employee.email }}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p>{{ employee.phone }}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p> <a href="" class="btn btn-tag">{{ employee.notes }}</a> </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p>{{ employee.status }}</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PANEL -->
</div>
<!-- END CONTAINER FLUID -->


<!-- MODAL STICK UP  -->
<div class="modal fade stick-up" id="addNewAppModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewAppModal" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="TableWithDynamicRowsCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header clearfix ">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="pg-close fs-14"></i>
                </button>
                <h4 class="p-b-5"><span class="semi-bold">New</span> Contact</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="small-text">Create a new contact using this form, make sure you fill all the fields in.</p>
                <form role="form" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input id="appName" type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default" >
                                <label>Company</label>
                                <input id="appCompany" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="company" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <input id="appAddress" type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="address" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input id="appCity" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="city" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>State</label>
                                <input id="appState" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="state" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default" ng-model="zip">
                                <label>ZIP</label>
                                <input id="appZip" type="text" class="form-control"  required>
                             
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default" ng-model="phone">
                                <label>Phone</label>
                                <input id="appPhone" type="text" class="form-control" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default" ng-model="email">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input id="appEmail" type="text" class="form-control" >
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default" ng-model="notes">
                                <label>Description</label>
                                <input id="appNotes" type="text"  required/>
                            
  </div> 
  
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div pg-form-group class="form-group form-group-default" ng-model="status">
                                <label>Status</label>
                                <input id="appStatus" type="text" class="form-control"   required>
                              
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="add-app" type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-cons" ng-click="addContact()">Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-cons" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- END MODAL STICK UP  -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#appPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function ran_col() { //function name
                var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
                var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0']; //Set your colors here
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
                document.getElementById('avatar').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: you need to define columns in your datatable

Comment: However, when you fill out the form, the data won't be displayed in the table. In the following image, if you look at the last object in the console to the right, the data is being passed through but not being displayed in the table: http://prnt.sc/f5zeig.

Comment: just like your object array structure: name, company, etc. Also make sure the names are exact, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: check my second comment

Comment: I'm not using a database.  I'm just displaying the data you see locally.

Comment: datatables has a property column. Jquerydatatables that is

Comment: for example: `datatable = $('#detailTable').DataTable({
            'paging': false,
            'ordering': false,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ItemId" },
                { "data": "ItemCode" },
                { "data": "ItemName" },
                { "data": "Uom" },
                { "data": "Qty" },
                { "data": "AllocationId" },
                { "data": "AllocationName" },
                { "data": "ExpenseCodeId" },
                { "data": "ExpenseCodeName" },
            ],`

Comment: then this is how i add my row to the table on the client: `$('#detailTable').DataTable().row.add(objectForm).draw(false);` So `objectForm` can be ether an object or an array. If you want to add multiple rows u need to use `.rows` method

Comment: Use the directive versions -> **http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/**

Answer (score 0):

You must define column property of your `datatable` when initializing it and inclue all the column your passing to you table in the column property.

So in your case it would be employee details:

```
table.DataTable({
        'paging': false,
        'ordering': false,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "company" },
            { "data": "address" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "phone" },
            { "data": "notes" },
            { "data": "status" },
        ],
        data: dataset})
```

So make sure all the column names correspond to your employee object.

Finally, when initializing the datatabale set `data` to an empty array. Like in the case above i assign it `dataset` (empty array). Otherwise datatable will fail to initialize.

Comment: For one column, I am inputting multiple entries like in the address column. Example, I am putting address, city, state, and zip in one column. Do I have to do anything different in the code snippet you provided to do this?

Comment: so your address is split into 3 columns?

Comment: or is commar delimited or similar

Comment: `<td class="v-align-middle">
                            <p>{{ employee.address }}<br> {{ employee.city }}, {{ employee.state }} {{ employee.zip }}</p>
                        </td>` It's being displayed like this in one column.

Comment: you can concatenate your address info and send it to the table, or take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519018/jquery-datatable-split-single-cell-into-multiple-columns-for-readability

Comment: but the main thing, are you able to add data to your table now?

Comment: It's passing through. Shows in the console, but refuses to display on the actual data table.http://prnt.sc/f5zeig

Comment: are u able to see any errors. Usually, when you are sending data to datatable and your columns are not defined correctly it will display and error. If it does not, then you either did not initialize it correctly or your not actually passing any data

Comment: i hope you did not copy and paste my snippet as my last column is set to status while your console shows your last column as state. So maybe try changing that if it is the case

Comment: also depending on the version of datatables that you are using check if the `addFnData` is the correct method. i use `DataTable().row.add(objectForm).draw(false);` for version:1.10.12

Comment: Sorry, my last row is actually status in the object. In the form, each entry has its own value in the object.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the code (I did paste your original snippet that you provided but tweaked it): http://prnt.sc/f5zs2n. Here is what turned up after I refreshed the page: http://prnt.sc/f5zshv

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because of your controller declaration.

Remove `ng-controller="TableWithDynamicRowsCtrl"` from `<div class="panel panel-transparent"...` and `<div class="modal fade stick-up" ...` and add it to body like 
`<body ng-controller="TableWithDynamicRowsCtrl">`

Or you can change `$scope` to `$rootScope`. Like change `$scope.employees = [...]` to  `$rootScope.employees = [...]` and `$scope.employees.push(...)` to `$rootScope.employees.push(...)`